# android date format: How to convert date in alphabets

Tags: java, android, android-date

How can I convert this date `26-11-2013` in this format `nov 26`. I have tried many things but didn't work for me. Like

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String dateInString = "26-11-2013";
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: do you wan to convert month to alphabetic one? 
look on that `M:1 MM:01 MMM:Jan MMMM:January MMMMM:J`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use another formatter for the desired output format.

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String dateInString = "26-11-2013";
Date date = inputFormat.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));
```